# How to Clear a View Frame

Tags: swiftui, ios14

I have a reset button in a view when tapped presents an alert that asks "Are you sure?" with options to tap either OK or Cancel. If the user taps Ok I would like for the button to disappear and display "All data has been deleted".  I tried placing code to display the last message under the alert, but I kept getting warnings about unused code so placed it down lower in the structure.  Currently when Ok is tapped the alert disappears and the code pushes the button to the top of the view and displays the completion message centered below. I'm guessing I need to delete the button frame, but not sure how to do that.

```
@EnvironmentObject var userData: UserData
@State private var resetSys: Bool = false
@State private var okTapped: Bool = false

var body: some View {
        ZStack {  
            Button(action: {
                self.resetSys.toggle()
                
            }) {
                RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 25)
                .fill(Color.green)
                .frame(width: 165, height: 85)

                Text("Reset Data?")
                    
            }.disabled(okTapped)
        }
        .navigationBarTitle("Reset Trip Data", displayMode: .inline)
        
        .alert(isPresented: $resetSys) {
            
            Alert(title: Text("Are you sure?"), primaryButton: .destructive (Text("OK")) {
                okTapped = true
                self.userData.resetSysData()
            },
            secondaryButton: .cancel()
            )
        }
        
        if okTapped == true {
        
            ZStack {
                Color.white
                Text("All Data has been Deleted")
        }
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure，maybe you need like this:

```
@EnvironmentObject var userData: UserData
@State private var resetSys: Bool = false
@State private var okTapped: Bool = false

var body: some View {
        ZStack {  
            if !self.okTapped {
                Button(action: {
                    self.resetSys.toggle()
                    
                }) {
                    RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 25)
                        .fill(Color.green)
                        .frame(width: 165, height: 85)
                    
                    Text("Reset Data?")
                    
                }.disabled(okTapped)
            } else {
                Color.white
                Text("All Data has been Deleted")
            }
        }
        .navigationBarTitle("Reset Trip Data", displayMode: .inline)
        .alert(isPresented: $resetSys) {
            
            Alert(title: Text("Are you sure?"), primaryButton: .destructive (Text("OK")) {
                okTapped = true
                self.userData.resetSysData()
            },
            secondaryButton: .cancel()
            )
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot leorider! It works great! I did have to add another ZStack around the RoundedRectangle and the text below to get the text on top of the colored button.